# Motion Artifact Cancellation from ECG Signal Using 3 Axis Accelerometer Data

Tags: denoising, adaptive-filters, least-squares

I have a ECG signal measured as a test subject is performing 3 different activities - sitting, walking(2mph) and jogging(5mph) and also the corresponding 3-axis accelerometer(X,Y and Z) signals. I can visually observe correlation between the amplitude of accelerometer signal and noise in the ECG signal for the 3 activities. The following are my questions,

1. How to decide on which axis of accelerometer data to use as noise feed to an adaptive LMS filter? Or should a combination of all 3 axes data be considered and if so, how?
2. Does the accelerometer data have to be normalized to the amplitude range of the ECG signal for effective performance of LMS filter?
3. What are the suggested parameters for the LMS filter for this case(The available literature is not clear on this problem).
4. For implementation in a embedded platform, is RL, LMS or NLMS suggested?